# How to deal with multiple h1 elements on subpages

Tags: html, accessibility, markup

According to the HTML5.1 spec, as outlined in the link below, every page should only have one `h1` element. Naturally, I feel that the `h1` element on the homepage should be a title describing the website itself. This raises the question, how do you correctly deal with `h1` headers on subpages if the `h1` element used on the homepage is used in `header`?

For instance, let's assume we are building a website for **Adam's Sweet Shop**, we create the layout and we create our header:

```
<header>
    <h1>Adam's Sweet Shop</h1>
    ...[other header elements]
</header>
```

Now, that works fine for the homepage. But as we delve into the subpages, we are left with two options. We create a different `h1` element describing that page and delegate the header `h1` into a different tag. This would seemingly satisfy the requirements of the HTML5.1 spec, but it almost seems 'hacky', plus for templates this would require two different *header* files.

The second option is to create two `h1` elements, one describing the website in the `header`, the other within the `main` element describing the page.

```
<header>
    <h1>Adam's Sweet Shop</h1>
    ...[other header elements]
</header>
<main>
    <h1>About Adam's Sweet Shop</h1>
    ...[other body elements]
</main>
```

This obviously goes against the HTML5.1 spec, but seems less hacky. I originally built a site using second approach, but received a *warning* message from the W3C validator.

Are either of these approaches correct, and if not, what is a better approach, for instance, an ARIA label describing the 'real' `h1`?

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements

Comment: The link seems to be missing ("According to the HTML5.1 spec, as outlined in the link below […]")

Comment: Generally your `<h1>` should match or be similar to your `<title>`, though there is no hard and fast rule (some will claim SEO justifies it). Do not use ARIA to try to spackle, just decide on a structure and be consistent throughout your site. In my world, I do not use `<h1>` in a `<header>`, thereby allowing it to be consistent across the site.

Comment: @unor I've added the link now.

Comment: @AdamMcquiff: Thanks. Where does it say that "every page should only have one `h1` element"?

Comment: It's implied, and the W3C validator returned a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works better in your site design to have an `h1` in the `header` and another `h1` in the `main`, then that’s what you should do. Neither the [canonical HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) nor the W3C copy of it say you shouldn’t use more than one `h1` element per document if that’s what meets your needs. And the [W3C HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)  won’t report any errors or warnings for the markup example in the question.

As far as any accessibility concerns, it’s true screen readers will report both those `h1` headings as being at the same (top) level, but that also seems appropriate for this particular case—it isn’t an absolute problem to have a couple top-level headings. (Though in contrast it would be a problem for screen readers if you marked up every section in your entire document with an `h1`—and that’s why the HTML emits warnings for that case (which is very different from your case).

Comment: I see, according to that canonical spec, you would be right. Who is the organisation responsible for maintaining that document? Also, I put a website with headings in the same format as the code in my example into the W3C Validator, and it threw _warning_ messages, implying that it was incorrect. Do you think these warnings can be ignored safely without affecting accessibility and SEO?

Comment: Neither of the examples in the question cause the checker to emit any warnings or errors: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3Etest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%3Cheader%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%3Ch1%3EAdam%2527s%2520Sweet%2520Shop%3C%252Fh1%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520...%255Bother%2520header%2520elements%255D%250D%250A%3C%252Fheader%3E#textarea

Comment: 2nd example: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3Etest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%3Cheader%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%3Ch1%3EAdam%2527s%2520Sweet%2520Shop%3C%252Fh1%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520...%255Bother%2520header%2520elements%255D%250D%250A%3C%252Fheader%3E%250D%250A%3Cmain%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%3Ch1%3EAbout%2520Adam%2527s%2520Sweet%2520Shop%3C%252Fh1%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520...%255Bother%2520body%2520elements%255D%250D%250A%3C%252Fmain%3E%250D%250A#textarea

Comment: The organization responsible for maintaining the spec I cited is the WHATWG

Comment: It would seem you are correct. I've had a play about with the validator to emulate the issue that was occurring to me. It was because my markup was similar to this:

Comment: URL: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3Etest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%3Cheader%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%3Ch1%3EAdam%2527s%2520Sweet%2520Shop%3C%252Fh1%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520...%255Bother%2520header%2520elements%255D%250D%250A%3C%252Fheader%3E%250D%250A%3Cmain%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%3Ch1%3EAbout%2520Adam%2527s%2520Sweet%2520Shop%3C%252Fh1%3E%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520...%255Bother%2520body%2520elements%255D%250D%250A%3C%252Fmain%3E%250D%250A#textarea

Comment: Yeah the markup example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079503/how-to-deal-with-multiple-h1-elements-on-subpages/42080886#42080886 will trigger a warning—but that’s different from the example in the question. Anyway I really do think the markup example in you question itself isn’t going to have adverse effects on anything or anybody. If I had reason to think otherwise, I’d already be having the HTML checker emit a warning for that kind of case too. :)

Answer (score 2):

*edit*

After reading [through](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only) [some](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/33) [discussions](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/110), I would no longer recommend using multiple `h1` tags if you care about assistive technologies or browser outlining until the implementations are standardized.

My original answer *should* be valid in the future and for SEO purposes, but there is no guarantee for that.

*original answer*

**You can have multiple `h1`s on a single page with the right sectioning.** In HTML5, document outlines are created differently from previous versions.

Before HTML5, the whole page was considered the "root document", and the `h1` was used to describe this root. It was a simple one-to-one relationship between HTML files and documents in the outline. This is important for SEO as engines use these outlines to guess what your page is about, and confusing them is a bad idea.

HTML5 introduced [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) such as `article`, `section`, `header`, `footer`, etc. According to the specs,

> Sectioning content is content that defines the scope of headings and footers.
>   Each sectioning content element potentially has a heading and an outline.

This means you can use a `h1` tag for every new outline created this way, because

> Certain elements are said to be sectioning roots, including blockquote and td elements. These elements can have their own outlines, but the sections and headings inside these elements do not contribute to the outlines of their ancestors.

so if you use a `h1` in a "child" outline created for example by nesting it in an `article`, it won't interfere with the outline (and thus SEO) of your parent outline.

So for all intents and purposes,

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            My awesome collection of articles
        </h1>
        [ ... some content ... ]
        <article>
            <h1>
                My awesome article
            </h1>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

is a valid use of headers and sectioning in HTML5. Also, [this article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824) does a great job at visually explaining all of this using nearly your example.

Comment: I originally had the same perspective, and, funnily enough, I used that article for reference, but I believe they have changed the way headers are used with HTML5.1, as my content was originally laid similar to your code, but I was receiving W3C Validator errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff Huh, this is what I get for repeating information I knew to be correct a year ago without checking. After doing some more research on the state of things, I'm not so sure about using multiple `h1` tags anymore based on [this w3c issue](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/169) from a few months back. [This message](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only) also has some interesting links at the bottom. It seems like they temporarily went back on their initial idea because of bad implementations and misuse of the elements by developers. (`h1` spam in `sections`, etc). (1/2)

Comment: @AdamMcquiff (2/2) Kind of sad, really. I think in the future this will be implemented correctly, but right now if you care about assistive technology  or browser outlining, it's better to stick to good ol' `h2`.  Concerning SEO, I didn't find any definitive sources on the subject, but I would hope search engines are better at implementing the new outlining model than browser vendors. I do use multiple `h1`s on some well ranking sites, but that's anecdotal evidence at best.

Comment: That's interesting, and I agree, it is kind of sad. It would seem that the spec proposed at HTML5 was the correct way and, like you've said, they've taken a step back. This question came about during working on a site that requires a high level of accessibility, so it's looks like I'm going to have to go with the poor version, for now!

Answer (score 2):

### HTML 5.1 has no restriction about having only one `h1`

The only requisits are:

> **The first element of heading content in an element of sectioning content represents the heading for that section**. Subsequent headings of equal or higher rank start new (implied) sections, headings of lower rank start implied subsections that are part of the previous one. In both cases, the element represents the heading of the implied section.

This means that :

- you must start with a `h1`,
- you have to respect the `h1`>`h2`>`h3`... hiererarchy,
- an heading starts a new section,
- but you can perfectly start a new section at the same level as your first one

So having one `h1` in both `main` and `header` sections is fine, according to the HTML specs,

### it's possible, but it's (often) bad design.

You should always consider that your `h1` is expected to be the webpage title (while the `<title>` element may already contain your website title). It makes no sense of having two titles for the webpage, for various reasons including SEO and accessibility.

So it's technically possible, HTML can be used for formatting complex multi-documents, but if you can avoid it, keep it simple.

Comment: Hi Adam, I see what you're saying, and I thought this was the case, but the W3C Validator was presenting warning messages when using multiple `h1` elements. Which approach would you recommend out of the two? Are either 'correct'?

Comment: @AdamMcquiff W3C validator only displays a warning when a h1 is used inside an inner section (which means that the hierarchy h1>h2>h3 is not respected because you'll have h1>h1). I would recommend using only one `h1` for the title of the page and enclosing the website title in a `header` tag.